# Prove common point is unique for a sequence of nested intervals...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The full question is this:
Let $I_1,I_2,...$ be a sequence of nested intervals. Assume in addition that $l_k = length(I_k)=b_k-a_k\rightarrow0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$. Prove that the common point is unique.

So I think the question wants me to show that there is only 1 common point as the intervals get smaller and smaller or for $[a_n, b_n]$ where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are both very close to each other but not equal to each other. But isn't there always real numbers in $[a_n,b_n]$ since no matter how close $a_n$ and $b_n$ are close to each other there will always be very small real numbers in between them.

So i know $a_n$ is an increasing bounded sequence and $b_n$ is a decreasing bounded sequence so $a_n$ converges to $a$ and $b_n$ converges to $b$ and we have $a_n\le a\le b\le b_n $ but $a$ doesn't have to equal to $b$ in this interval when $a_n$, $b_n$ are really close to each other. So I don't think theres a unique or 1 common point, but the question wants me to show that there is, so I am misunderstanding something and I can't see it.

Comment: Assume $x,y\in I_n$ for all $n$. What can you say about $|x-y|$?

Comment: @user251257 $a_n\le|x-y|\le b_n$ for all n

Comment: that doesn't make sense. Assume additionally $x\le y$. What an you say about $|x-y| = y - x$?

Comment: @user251257 I wanted to say $|x-y| \le |a_n-b_n|$ for all n. $|x-y| = y-x$ if $y$ is greater than $x$

Comment: And the rhs $|a_n - b_n|$ converges to?

Comment: @user251257 $|a_n-b_n| \rightarrow 0$ so $|x-y| \le 0$ and that can only be satisfied if x-y = 0 since $|x-y|$ can only have positive values. Therefore x and y are equal to each other?

Comment: yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

The unique common point is
$$c = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_n = \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}}b_n.$$
You can show that if $x$ is a common point of the $I_n$, then $x \geq \sup a_n$ and $x \leq \inf a_n$. The hypothesis that $b_n - a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ allows you to show that $\sup a_n = \inf b_n$.

Comment: So the common point $c$ means that $a_n$ and $b_n$ converges to the same number which is the common point $c$?